# Lightning rich text field is producing different html depending on the age of the record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to debug an issue where I have a lightning rich text field on a page.

lightning:inputRichText aura:id="Desc"

With the input in the UI as "A new para"

For a new/newer record, it saves the following HTML: `<p>A new para</p>`

But if I edit an old record say from pre 2021, I get the following saved: `A new para`

It is not adding the p tags.

Why is this happening?

I know the lightning rich text component was improved a few years ago to add para tags and replace divs etc. Which is fine.

But why when I edit an old record, does it do something else?